# How the user data can be fetched for the Google play store Account deletion Requirement - Google Play’s app account deletion url,

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, google-play

recently i came across the data security policy of google play store, and making a way to delete the account outside of the app.

This was the reference of the google play store policy.
Google Play’s app account deletion requirements
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/13327111?hl=en

here it is mentioned to delete the account by providing a url to the web resource.

so it is outside of the application, in the play store, so how the user data can be fetched for the deletion of the account.

if it is inside the app, we can get the respective access_token, via those token we can remove the user data on web resource.

have researched a lot, but didnt find a solution for this.

Ruby On Rails, Ruby, Rails